# How to display a partciular column from a database in a tableview in QT

Tags: qt

I want to show a particular column from my database in a tableview.Can anyone please tell me how to do it?

Comment: One way is: https://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qsqlquerymodel.html#details  look at the example.

Comment: What have you _already_ tried?